# where can I find graph input resources/files?

Tags: algorithm, file, input, dataset, graph

I want to test various algorithms on graphs.
Does anyone know a web where I can get lots of examples in text files?
I've found many examples but they are always images. I want a text description
of a graph, by edge listing or whatever... do you know one such source?

Thanks!
Manuel

Comment: Write a program to randomly generate them...

Comment: Yeah... that's a good idea, but I thought that perhaps an online repo existed. Don't you know one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Graph problems are common in programming competitions.

I don't know if you are used to the format of those competitions, but here's a list
of some of the online judges where you can submit/test your solution online:

- [UVA](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/) (Probably the biggest ACM problems database, to help you, here's a [list of some graph problems](http://shygypsy.com/acm/cgi-bin/grepplus.pl?keywords=graph))
- [Spoj](http://www.spoj.pl)
- [SGU](http://acm.sgu.ru/)

[Topcoder](http://topcoder.com/tc) has also a great problem database (see [problem archive](http://www.topcoder.com/tc?module=ProblemArchive)) But it'll take you some time to get used to it. (Note that it's not just the problems, you can also use the arena to test/submit your solutions)

Comment: what I want is graph inputs to test my own algorithms, not problems to create algoritms... Isn't' there a repo where I can download input files containing graphs for algorithm testing? Thanks!

Comment: Well, you'll find many problems to test your algorithms, some problems are just applications for a given algorithm. Besides that, with input files you won't know if your output is correct or not, while in an online judge, you'll get an evaluation of your result

Comment: Most competitions put the data used for judging submissions on the web after the competition is complete. Look for problems where the input is a graph and find the judge input file for that problem.

Answer (score 1):

RDF datasets are graphs, try [rdfdata.org](http://www.rdfdata.org/data.html), [dbpedia](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/Downloads32) which is wikipedia in RDF, the [LUBM](http://swat.cse.lehigh.edu/projects/lubm/) graph benchmark, or a [really big one](http://vmlion25.deri.ie/) (currently down at 2009-11-19 21:18 GMT).

Also [wordnet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/) is a graph.

Answer (score 1):

Or go to the source, [The Stanford Graphbase](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/sgb.html).